# Do you still wrap an NSScrollView around an NSView in Interface Builder via a menu?

Tags: xcode4, nsscrollview

"Layout> Make subviews of > Scroll View."

This is the instruction in the NSScrollView programming guide for how to use IB to wrap a Scrollview around a view. But it appears this option no longer exists in XCode 4.

So how do you wrap a Scrollview around a View in XCode 4 (Cocoa programming, no iOS programming).

And don't say "embed" because that doesn't work either.

M